# Creating a dataframe after extracting value from an oddly nested dictionary of a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am loading a tricky (to me) dataset from an API that is in the format `{[{}]}` and I need to create a dictionary by pairing the items in a list with a specific set of values found in their respective dataset.

```
lis = ['A', 'B']
for i in lis:
    chata = requests.get(urlhalf1 + i + urlhalf2)
    chart = json.loads(chata.text)
    print(chart)
```

Sample *output* **for item 'A'** in `lis` (B is not shown):

```
{'symbol': 'A', 'historical': [{'date': '2018-06-28', 'volume': 78952, 'changePercent': 5.55}, {'date': '2018-06-27', 'volume': 95867, 'changePercent': 2.22}]}
```

I would like to extract the values from key, 'changePercent' from this sample output of 'A' and somehow get to this following output:

```
data = {'A': [5.55, 2.22], 'B': [3.33, 4.44]}
```

With this format I would like to make a dataframe with a row for each key, value pair and with the index being [1, 2] (In this example). My code attempt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data), index = [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to get all the `changePercent` values into a list.

```
data = {}
lis = ['A', 'B']
for i in lis:
    chata = requests.get(urlhalf1 + i + urlhalf2)
    chart = chata.json()
    print(chart)
    data[i] = [h['changePercent'] for h in chart['historical']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and I hope it'll help:

```
chart = {'symbol': 'A', 'historical': [{'date': '2018-06-28', 'volume': 78952, 'changePercent': 5.55}, {'date': '2018-06-27', 'volume': 95867, 'changePercent': 2.22}]}

data = {'A' : chart['historical'][0]['changePercent'], 'B' : chart['historical'][1]['changePercent']}
print(data)
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76499696/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
data = {
    i: [
        d["changePercent"]
        for d in requests.get(f"{urlhalf1}{i}{urlhalf2}").json()["historical"]
    ] for i in lis
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=range(1, len(data)+1))
```

Output:

```
print(df)

     A    B
1 5.55 3.33
2 2.22 4.44
```